# how to remove indentation from avatar in messageKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, messagekit

I removed the avatar from the chat, and I was able to move the message itself, but I could not move the date of the message. How to do it?

There is also another question: I have a message date written after every four messages. How to make time written only when the next day begins?

On the screen is an example of what happened.

[image]

```
class ChatsViewController: MessagesViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let layout = messagesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.textMessageSizeCalculator.outgoingAvatarSize = .zero
            layout.textMessageSizeCalculator.incomingAvatarSize = .zero
            layout.photoMessageSizeCalculator.outgoingAvatarSize = .zero
            layout.photoMessageSizeCalculator.incomingAvatarSize = .zero
            layout.attributedTextMessageSizeCalculator.incomingAvatarSize = .zero
            layout.attributedTextMessageSizeCalculator.outgoingAvatarSize = .zero
            layout.attributedTextMessageSizeCalculator.avatarLeadingTrailingPadding = .zero
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - MessagesDataSource
extension ChatsViewController: MessagesDataSource {
    
    func cellTopLabelAttributedText(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {
        if indexPath.item % 4 == 0 {
            return NSAttributedString(
                string: MessageKitDateFormatter.shared.string(from: message.sentDate),
                attributes: [
                    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10),
                    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.1176470588, green: 0.4470588235, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)])
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func messageBottomLabelAttributedText(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {
        
        return NSAttributedString(string: MessageKitDateFormatter.shared.string(from: message.sentDate), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)])
    }
    
}

// MARK: - MessagesLayoutDelegate
extension ChatsViewController: MessagesLayoutDelegate {
    
    func footerViewSize(for section: Int, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 8)
    }
    
    func cellTopLabelHeight(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> CGFloat {
        if (indexPath.item) % 4 == 0 {
            return 30
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func messageBottomLabelHeight(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> CGFloat {
        return 16
    }
}

// MARK: - MessagesDisplayDelegate
extension ChatsViewController: MessagesDisplayDelegate {
    
    func configureAvatarView(_ avatarView: AvatarView, for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) {
        avatarView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func avatarSize(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> CGSize {
        return .zero
    }
    
    func messageStyle(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> MessageStyle {
        return .bubble
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `setMessageIncomingMessageBottomLabelAlignment` and `setMessageOutgoingMessageBottomLabelAlignment` methods on the flow layout to adjust the bottom label alignment like this:

```swift
        messagesCollectionView.messagesCollectionViewFlowLayout.setMessageIncomingMessageBottomLabelAlignment(LabelAlignment(textAlignment: .left, textInsets: .zero))
        messagesCollectionView.messagesCollectionViewFlowLayout.setMessageOutgoingMessageBottomLabelAlignment(LabelAlignment(textAlignment: .right, textInsets: .zero))
```

To answer your second question, you could keep around a variable in your class `var lastDisplayedSentDate: Date?` and in your `cellTopLabelAttributedText` method, check whether the lastDisplayedSentDate is in the same day as the current message, return `nil` if they are in the same day, else return the date string and update the `lastDisplayedSentDate` variable:

```swift
        if let lastDisplayedSentDate = lastDisplayedSentDate, Calendar.current.isDate(lastDisplayedSentDate, inSameDayAs: message.sentDate) {
            return nil
        }
        lastDisplayedSentDate = message.sentDate
        
        return NSAttributedString(
                string: MessageKitDateFormatter.shared.string(from: message.sentDate),
                attributes: [
                    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10),
                    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.1176470588, green: 0.4470588235, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)])
```

and you can add similar logic to the `cellTopLabelHeight` method.